# excel multi-select pick list VBA doesnt run on password protect sheet

Tags: excel, vba, protected

**Any thoughts on how to change this to allow multiselect to run on password protected sheet without having to key in the password?**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Dim num As Integer

On Error GoTo Exitsub

If Target.Address = "$H$29" Or Target.Address = "$H$33" Or Target.Address = "$H$37" Or Target.Address = "$H$42" Or Target.Address = "$H$58" Or Target.Address = "$H$59" Or Target.Address = "$H$60" Or Target.Address = "$H$63" Or Target.Address = "$H$65" Or Target.Address = "$M$29" Or Target.Address = "$M$33" Or Target.Address = "$M$37" Or Target.Address = "$M$42" Or Target.Address = "$M$58" Or Target.Address = "$M$59" Or Target.Address = "$M$60" Or Target.Address = "$M$63" Or Target.Address = "$M$65" Then
    If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
    Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Newvalue = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        Oldvalue = Target.Value
        If Oldvalue = "" Then
            Target.Value = Newvalue
        Else
            num = InStr(Oldvalue, Newvalue)
            If num = 0 Then ' If the element selected isnt already on the selected list
              Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
            ElseIf num = 1 Then ' If the element is the first on the list
              If Len(Oldvalue) = Len(Newvalue) Then ' If the element is the only element selected
                Target.Value = Replace(Oldvalue, Newvalue, "")
              Else                                  ' If the element is not the only element selected
                Target.Value = Replace(Oldvalue, Newvalue & ", ", "")
              End If
            ElseIf num > 1 Then  ' If the element is not the first
              Target.Value = Replace(Oldvalue, ", " & Newvalue, "")
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: First thing noticed: replace the `If Target.Address = this or that or this or that` use `If Intersect(Target, This, That, This, That)`. Not a problem - more of a best practice

Comment: Your code will need to unprotect the sheet before it makes any changes, then re-protect it when done.  Having said that though, how is the user making the change which triggers the macro, if the sheet is protected against changes?

Comment: User simply clicks one of the multi-select picklist fields mentioned above (i.e.$h$29) and the macro allows him to select multiple values. But as soon as I protect the sheet it will only show a single value.

Comment: Uncomment your error handler and run the code - where does it error and what is the error message?

Comment: Just not sure what to add and where to insert - I've tried some user interfaceonly only approach but I'm probably inserting it incorrectly.

Comment: `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)` throws an error on a protected sheet

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 unprotect the sheet, run your code, then protect it again using VBA (but this can be insecure when the macro is stopped in the middle)

Option 2 protect the sheet using this code

```
ActiveSheet.Protect "password", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

that way the sheet is protected only from user changes, not macro changes.

Comment: Worksheet protection is not a security feature.

Answer (score 0):

`SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)` throws an error on a protected sheet

This will work on a protected sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const SEP As String = ","
    Dim c As Range, NewValue, OldValue, arr, v, lst, removed As Boolean

    On Error GoTo Exitsub

    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub '<< only handling single-cell changes

    'is the changed cell in our monitored range?
    Set c = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B5,B7,B9,B11")) ' for example

    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 And Not c.Validation Is Nothing Then

            Application.EnableEvents = False
            NewValue = c.Value
            Application.Undo
            OldValue = c.Value

            If OldValue = "" Then
                c.Value = NewValue
            Else
                arr = Split(OldValue, SEP)
                'loop over previous list, removing newvalue if found
                For Each v In arr
                    If v = NewValue Then
                        removed = True
                    Else
                        lst = lst & IIf(lst = "", "", SEP) & v
                    End If
                Next v
                'add the new value if we didn't just remove it
                If Not removed Then lst = lst & IIf(lst = "", "", SEP) & NewValue
                c.Value = lst
            End If
        End If    'has validation and non-empty
    End If        'handling this cell

Exitsub:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work at allowing me to have multiple multi select drop downs with protected cells and be able to filter and sort selected items.

I locked the cells I wanted protected with formatting and used this DBA code to protect the locked cells without keeping the VBA code from working.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' To allow multiple selection to work along with filtering and sorting while sheet is protected

ActiveSheet.Protect "password", UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
' To allow multiple selections in a Drop Down List in Excel (without repetition)
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Column = 1 Or Target.Column = 5 Or Target.Column = 6 Or Target.Column = 7 Or Target.Column = 18 Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & vbNewLine & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```